# Spatie/Laravel-Permissions: Undefined method translationEnabled() error

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

I am working on Laravel project that is using the following libraries:

- Spatie/Laravel-Permissions
- Laravel-Backpack Base, Crud
- Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager

Every time, I try to create new role or permission from the admin interface, I get the this error:

> Call to undefined method Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::translationEnabled()

I have already done the necessary setup, but cant seem make this work.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The error is triggered by a call on line 1 of this view:

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/form_content.blade.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: May be this will help you-- https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/10

Comment: Can you please show some code. Share your models, that way you'll get better help.

Comment: @AhmadUlHoqNadim I have already added HasRole trait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. I had already installed Spatie/Laravel-Permissions before installing Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager which require the same library. However, I had made some changes to the config that had overwritten the configuration for PermissionManager which caused the error. Removing those configurations solved the issue.

Comment: How you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace default Roles and Permission models on backup's

in  the file `config/permission.php` replace:

```
'permission' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::class,    
to
'permission' => \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Permission::class,
```

And

```
'role' => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::class,
to
'role' => \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Its VS Code related problem. I resolved it using below solution.

Ctrl + Shift + P // To open the editor commands

// then type in or scroll down and select...

> Developer:Reload Window